# Does Django have any text file search features?

Tags: django, inverted-index

I am using Django Web Framework to store PDF files in FileFields, that will then be converted to .txt files to be used later. Does Django have any features to parse files for queries? My first thought if they diddn't was to use a simple Inverted Index, but I wanted to utilize Django tools as much as I can.

I've done several searches in the Django documentation but haven't found anything. I know that the chance of Django having a feature like this was quite low.